# Conditional Form getting name

Tags: php, forms

Im doing a conditional form and as far as I can tell everything is correct except its just not working correctly. im trying to pass my values into a if statement and its just not getting them, it keeps echoing out my else statement.

This is what I have

```
    <form action="" method="post">
<select name="optionType" onChange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="Ben">Ben</option>
<option value="John">John</option>
<option value="Matt">Matt</option>
</select>
</form>

<table>

<? 
for($x=2; $x<=count($excel->sheets[0]["cells"]); $x++) {
    $date = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
    $user = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][2];
    $type = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][3];
    $keywords = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][4];
    $keywordpage = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][5];
    $urls = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][6];
    $sitepr = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][7];

    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    if($user == $_POST['optionType']) {
        echo "<td>";
    echo $date = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][1];
    echo "</td>\n";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $user = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][2];
    echo "</td>\n";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $type = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][3];
    echo "</td>\n";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $keywords = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][4];
    echo "</td>\n";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $keywordpage = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][5];
    echo "</td>\n";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $urls = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][6];
    echo "</td>\n";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $sitepr = $excel->sheets[0]["cells"][$x][7];
    echo "</td>\n";
    }else{
    echo 'Nothing at this time';
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}

    ?>
    </table>
```

Any help is appreciated
thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with `value="<?php echo $userinfo = 'Ben'; ?>"`? Why not `value="Ben"`? In fact, I wonder why you use `echo $var = 'value';` everywhere... Is there a field named `userinfo` that you expect post data from? `$user` is not defined at the place in your script where you're checking its value?

Comment: its for my code further down the line, updated my code so you could get a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is this `$_POST['userinfo']`. Your select box isn't named `userinfo`. It's named `optionType`. So you never get a user passed from your form.

Comment: Yeah I changed it to option type as well and its still the same result

Comment: And are you positive you're getting a value from the variable `$user`? Try echoing both `$user` and `$_POST['optionType']` to see what the values are before the if statement. Just to make sure you're getting the proper value from `$user`